# Firebase Notification, not displaying when in background or killed, but data is sent

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I have this app, that recieves push notifications from a php based server, the push notification is a data payload that contains a url that automatically opens in a webview when clicked.

My app works, but not in the way I want it to work.
I am able to send push notifcations from my php server, but the notification shows only when the app is in the foreground, but when it is on the background it does not display.

When I check the logcat, i discovered that the json data is sent from the server, even when the app is in the background.  **What could be preventing the push notification from displaying when the app is in background or killed?**

Below is my FirebaseMessaging Class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
private final String CHANNEL_ID="notificcation";
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);

}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
 handleMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get(Config.STR_KEY));

}

private void handleMessage(String message) {
    Intent pushNotification=new Intent(Config.STR_PUSH);
    pushNotification.putExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE,message);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

    }



  }
```

**Here is my PHP script**

```
   <?php

   require "init.php";
   $message=$_POST['message'];
   $title=$_POST['title'];
   $url=$_POST['url'];


   $path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
   $server_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

   $sql="SELECT fcm_token FROM fcm_info";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

   $key=$row['fcm_token'];
    }


   $headers=array(

    'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
    'Content-Type:application/json'

     );

        $fields=array(
        'to'=>$key,
        'data'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,'webUrl'=>$url));

        $payload=json_encode($fields);

        $curl_session=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

        $result=curl_exec($curl_session);
        mysqli_close($con);

         ?>
```

**My Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReciever;
private final String CHANNEL_ID="notificcation";
String app_server_url="http:/xxxxxxxxxxx/insert.php";





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    if(webView.canGoBack()){

        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        builder.setTitle("Do you want to leave the App?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog=builder.show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token=sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),"");


    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, app_server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String>params=new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("fcm_token",token);
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);


    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://default_website");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if(dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



    mRegistrationBroadcastReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.STR_PUSH))
            {

                String message=intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE);
                showNotification("Article",message);



            }

        }

    };


    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    if(intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY)!=null)
    {
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_KEY));


    }
}

private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
    notificationChannel();
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.app_launcher);


    Intent intent =new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Config.STR_KEY,message);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sms_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(picture)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());




}

private void notificationChannel (){

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        CharSequence name="Personal Notificaiton";
        String description="include";
        int importance=NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name,importance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);


    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,new IntentFilter("registration Complete"));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReciever,new IntentFilter(Config.STR_PUSH));
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I suggest you to do not use `LocalBroadcastManager` until you have work in some work in activity.
to solve your you need to write `showNotification` method in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` and call it directly.

if you still have some work in activity you need to use something as following code block

> MyFirebaseMessagingService=>onMessageReceived()

```
 if (!isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
    Intent pushNotification=new Intent(Config.STR_PUSH);
    pushNotification.putExtra(Config.STR_MESSAGE,message);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
    } else {
      showNotification("Article",message);
    }
```

and add following method which checks app is in background or not

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

Don't forget to define method in  MyFirebaseMessagingService 
`private void showNotification(String title, String message)`